# Intermittent Error Message in Eclipse Console Window

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm starting to learn the Eclipse environment, and occasionally when I type in some code and hit "F11" (to save, compile & run), I get a successful compilation and run of my program, followed by this in red text at the bottom of the console window:

```
ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [../../../src/share/back/util.c:820]
```

It only happens sometimes, and I've yet to find a pattern (open windows or perspectives, saving before or not, etc). A minute ago, it was happening every other time, and now I can't get it to happen at all. In all cases, the (very simple) program is running to completion correctly. I'm guessing it has to do with the way I've got the environment set up, but really, I just downloaded the darn thing off the internet and ran it, so whatever I have should be pretty "vanilla".

Doesn't really hurt anything, I guess - just curious. I tend not to like random error messages popping up during the software development process that I don't understand.

Relevant details, in case it helps:

- Eclipse SDK, Version: 3.4.2, Build id: M20090211-1700
- Eclipse Java Development Tools, Version: 3.4.2.r342_v20081217-7o7tEAoEEDWEm5HTrKn-svO4BbDI, Build id: M20090211-1700
- Eclipse Platform, Version: 3.4.2.R342_v20090122-9I96EiWElHi8lheoJKJIvhM3JfVsYbRrgVIWL, Build id: M20090211-1700
- Eclipse Project SDK, Version: 3.4.2.R342_v20090122-7O7S7GApJ3_vCyk7ETmsfcmjhz0eHnqw7MIjk9Vdhe4Ic
  Build id: M20090211-1700

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that similar to that [Java Sun bug 6476706](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6476706)?
If yes, what exact version of JDK are you using for your project in Eclipse?

It is said:

> Error disappeared with the addition of `System.exit(0)` at the end of the main method.

It can also be an error ([package directive missing](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5159038)) in the source files of your project.

Comment: That sure looks like it. One comment says "It sounds like a timing issue in the shutdown with the agent still running.", which would make sense, as timing issues are frequently intermittent.

My JDK compliance level is set to 1.6.

Comment: (And sorry if this was a LMGTFU ... I did try googling the error message, honest, but I didn't get this in my results.)

Comment: @Ian: no problem. I would rather have that problem referenced here on SO than "out there". Thank you for the feedback.